# How to analyse data collected through a sensor every minute?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-analysis, analysis

I have a dataset from a sensor which collected air quality features like CO2, temperature etc every minute for 30 days.

I have tried pandas and tableu but I don't seem to get anywhere. Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Usually using sampled data is the better option for Time-Series data analysis. You can refer [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/76511) answer to know more about the sampling and how it is useful for time-series data analysis.